# PrimeNg table lazy load not firing when first property is changed

Tags: angular, primeng, lazy-loading, primeng-table

I am using PrimeNg p-table. I need to go to the last page, and for that I am changing the first property. The page is changing in the paginator links, but lazy load is not firing and thus, I am not able to fetch the data for that page.

Why is lazy load not firing? Any help would be be appreciated. :)

Comment: If you share with us your code it will help

Comment: I cannot share code, since it's on Client's machine. :(

Comment: Which property are you changing?

Comment: How did you implement the paginator ?